# Subtraction of two images

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get the difference of `pixel` values in two images.

```
out_img = cv2.imread(output_path)
tar_img = cv2.imread(target_path)
difference = out_img - tar_img
```

But I didn’t get a desirable result, so I checked how `subtraction` worked, looking at a specific `pixel`.

```
print out_img[0][0] #shows [254 254 254]
print tar_img[0][0] #shows [255 255 255]
print out_img[0][0] - tar_img[0][0] #this should show [-1 -1 -1], but shows [255 255 255]
```

What causes this?

Comment: opencv's subtraction method would use a saturation cast, to truncate the result to 0 instead of getting an underflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `images` that you read in to a `data` `type` that supports negative numbers, such as `unsigned int 8` (`np.int8`). This can be done with `.astype()`:

```
out_img = cv2.imread(output_path).astype(np.int8)
tar_img = cv2.imread(target_path).astype(np.int8)
difference = out_img - tar_img
```

The reason that you were getting the problem before, is that `cv2.imread()` returns a `numpy` `array` with `data` `type` `unsigned int 8`. So when you try and store a value in it a as `-1`, this loops around to `255`.

We can demonstrate this with a simpler example:

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint8)
>>> a[0] = -1
>>> a
array([255,   2,   3,   4], dtype=uint8)
```

However, if we convert `a` to the `signed int datatype` (`np.int8`), we can do this in the expected way:

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint8)
>>> a = a.astype(np.int8)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int8)
>>> a[0] = -1
>>> a
array([-1,  2,  3,  4], dtype=int8)
```

Hopefully this clears some things up for you!

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct.  Pixels are stored as 8-bit unsigned numbers; their range is 0-255.  `-1` is not a supported value in this type; the arithmetic wraps around to the top of the range again, losing the supposed sign bit to overflow.

You would have a similar effect with addition: 255 + 1 => 0